# How to render .xib (custom view) programmatically by NSClassFromString?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xib

I am new to Swift.
Currently I have made serval xib files and they can be rendered in the following codes

```
    let mySubview:customView = customView(frame: CGRect(x:10,y:300, width: 312, height:355))
    self.view.addSubview(mySubview)
```

"customView" is the custom view (.xib) file while there are many others. However, I want to render it with a function parameter. I have used string but I got an error for this:

```
func addComp(name:String){
   let className = NSClassFromString("MyApp."+name) as! UIView.Type
   let subview = className.init()
  subview.frame = CGRect(x:10,y:300, width: 312, height:355)
  self.view.addSubview(subview)
   }
```

It says

> "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Anyway, is there any ways to define a custom view with function parameters? Either with string or any other methods.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with _xib_ files. There are no _xib_ files anywhere in your code.

Comment: Make sure modulo name is same name as your app name.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're coming at this wrong. Don't turn a string to a type; use a type directly.

Here's a UIView subclass with a factory method that does everything your `addComp` does:

```
class MyFactoryView : UIView {
    required override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    }
    static func make(andAddTo v:UIView) {
        let subv = self.init(frame:CGRect(x:10,y:300, width: 312, height:355))
        v.addSubview(subv)
    }
}
```

Okay, so let's say we have some subclasses of that type:

```
class MyView1 : MyFactoryView {}
class MyView2 : MyFactoryView {}
```

So now there's no need for any string. To enact our little drama, we just talk directly to the type; for example:

```
MyView1.make(andAddTo:self.view)
```